# Cross-Browser PHP Sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies

As I have a website with a multi step process (filling in different forms) I would like to now if using PHP Sessions is the best way to identify the user when switching from page to page. What is the best practice to do that? What if browser cookies are not available?

Answer (score 1):

Sessions would be the 'standard' approach. Sessions are not cookies, you can still use sessions even if cookie are not available, but that's quite uncommon now.

Comment: Sessions are cookies, they're just stored on the server :)

Comment: but that's just gong to confuse the OP

Comment: Sessions aren't cookies, but they don't work without cookies (they depend on cookies to propagate the session ID in normal circumstances.  The other mechanism for propagating session IDs via $_GET is dangerously insecure and never used any more).

Comment: @AlienWebguy I know, but its all about the session id.